# Не могу настроить Git Bash на Windows 10

Tags: git, git-bash

Запускаю Git Bash после установки, выдает вот это:

```
0 [main] bash 8088 fork: child 1220 - died waiting for dll loading, errno 11
bash: fork: retry: Resource temporarily unavailable
1115718 [main] bash 8088 fork: child 6736 - died waiting for dll loading, errno 11
bash: fork: retry: Resource temporarily unavailable
3229691 [main] bash 8088 fork: child 4044 - died waiting for dll loading, errno 11
bash: fork: retry: Resource temporarily unavailable
7342395 [main] bash 8088 fork: child 5584 - died waiting for dll loading, errno 11
bash: fork: retry: Resource temporarily unavailable
15455414 [main] bash 8088 fork: child 6208 - died waiting for dll loading, errno 11
bash: fork: Resource temporarily unavailable
bash-4.4$
```

В чем трабл???

Comment: На всякий случай: откуда вы устанавливали Git?

Comment: В смысле с какого сайта?  https://git-scm.com/download/win

Comment: Попробуйте вот эти инструкции. http://stackoverflow.com/a/43329696/2790048

Comment: Ну как, получилось что-нибудь?

Comment: выполнил эти инструкции:  1. Adding Git folder to File Rating > File List as trusted file
2. Adding Git folder to Advanced protection > Milanescious > Shell code exclusion
3. Setting bit-bash.exe as allowed application in Firewall > Application Rules (this one may be optional, but it won't hurt anyway)      вроде заработало но выдает следующее:

Comment: mkdir: cannot create directory '/dev/shm': Read-only file system

Creating /dev/shm directory failed.
POSIX semaphores and POSIX shared memory will not work

mkdir: cannot create directory '/dev/mqueue': Read-only file system

Creating /dev/mqueue directory failed.
POSIX message queues will not work

ln: failed to create symbolic link '/dev/stdin': Read-only file system
ln: failed to create symbolic link '/dev/stdout': Read-only file system
ln: failed to create symbolic link '/dev/stderr': Read-only file system...      Но это вроде не значительные ошибки. Большое СПАСИБО!!!